# C# : Serialize objects to XML without reflection

Tags: c#, xml, linq, serialization, reflection

In an application, we can save the current state of the application and it's configuration(which can be huge). We are using the `XmlSerializer`.

We now have only what we need in the XML(all XmlIgnore are in place), and it's VERY slow to store the whole configuration(file of ~50-100MB).

We NEED to keep storing this configuration as XML, but we would like to avoid :

- The reflection, which is to slow
- To implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface

The idea was to have a method to implement in each object, in which we can register which fields/property we want to serialize, then having a `SerializationManager` which is able to read what we want to serialize, and then write them.

Like this, objects doesn't know the language (XML) in which they will be rendered, and if one day we want a binary serialization(or if we want to have the possibility to serialize in different format), we can.

But we don't want to reinvent the wheel, and I don't know if some library exists or if something like Linq to xml can help, or if this is natively possible, ...

So how do you think I can achieve this?

Comment: 100 MB of configuration in any kind of format is a bad idea IMHO. You should use a database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The reflection, which is to slow"

Except, it doesn't use reflection at runtime. It performs metaprogramming on the first run (assuming you are using `new XmlSerializer(type)`) to inspect the type and generate *static code* that will work on the given type. Therefore, any volume-related performance issue is not related to reflection. There *is* a chance that the metaprogramming *itself* can take a measurable time, but a: this is unlikely unless your model is *really* complicated, and b: it can be avoided by using the [sgen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tool to pre-generate the serialization assembly.

Any performance issue, therefore, is most likely due to the size of the model and the overhead of xml.

If you want to try a different serializer, consider something like protobuf-net. You won't be able to read the data (it will not be xml), but the output will be much smaller and faster.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned

> In an application, we can save the current **state** of the application and it's **configuration**

*State*, especially when it is big (100Mb is ... huge!), required its own way to serialize data. Many of us knows and hates that slow saving/loading game saves from past. Even now, game developers distinguish *quicksave* from ordinal saves. It is optimized to occurs faster (to example, by caching part of recently performed quicksave) than ordinal save.

First question is why XML? `BinarySerializer` is faster, but for sizes like this you better use manual serialization (as Marc Gravell suggested, use protobuf, it's ultimate superior to anything).

Second question is, do you really need *serialize* data (change their format)? The fastest way of saving state is to dump memory. Imagine you have all your data saved in one block of memory, then dumping this block into a file is a very quick save. You may (I am not sure, but it should be doable) construct your data in a way, what overriding this memory will be kind of *loading* game. This much faster of any conversion.

If you go with *dumping*, then consider to pack it (into zip). Packing and saving 10 mb should be faster than saving unpacked 100 mb (assuming, you are not using too slow or too good packing algorithm), memory operations and cpu are much faster than SSD.

To save configuration, you can still serialize it as usual. If you want it to be a single file, then define own format of this file, to example:

```
config_stream, separator["<<<>>>>"], memory block [100 Mb]
```

Serialize with `XmlSerializer` into memory, create file, save config, separator, dump.

Comment: 100MB huge --> Agreed, worst case scenario, our usual cases are 20MB. Why XML? Because we have some hardware with embedded software that has to read *parts* of configuration. Same response for your second question

Comment: Ok, so you have to stick to XML. Could you change format of it? Instead of serializing `double[1234567]` you could convert it to byte array, possibly zip, encode and then save as a single element of xml.

Comment: We don't have huge array usually. Some parts can changes, some other not(those who are sent to the hardware).

Comment: You mentioned *parts of configuration*, perhaps you can separate *other* things, call them *state* and behave differently with them to achieve performance?

Comment: The thing is that we have a notion of version, so we have to provide some XSLT for each changes we do on the XML, and we have to provide it  for both XML saved locally, or the one that hardware device can return us.

Comment: If other devices, each, have to read 100 mb (through some communications) to simple obtain their 10kb configuration part, then you have wrong design. Perhaps you have to split that you call *configuration* to be like multiple small configurations (to example, UI config, method settings, standards used, deviceA settings) and then among them also *state* somewhere?

Comment: No, the configuration is composed of hundred of devices, each device receives only the part they are interessted in(I don't want to much in details, but we have in addition some servers, which have to receive the same TOTAL xml.